# What's the difference between Android Gradle tasks `lint` and `lintAnalyze`

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

The docs are very vague. I've even traced the source code and it appears `lintAnalyze` sends a flag `--analyze-only` to the CLI. The CLI has no reference to this string though as far as I can see, so in effect the two commands do the same thing.

What am I missing?